# Increasing expansion rate and time dilation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, space-expansion

Does the increasing dispersion of matter that occurs as the universe expands impact time (and therefore observed speed) for older/further compared to newer/closer events being observed simultaneously from earth? How do physicists know that the observed increasing rate of expansion of the universe is not the effect of gravitational time dilation for earlier relative to later events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravitational time dilation is due to spatial differences in the potential. In the FLRW/ΛCDM cosmology we assume spatial homogenity and isotropy, so there is no overall time dilation. Nevertheless the observed duration of events is dilated the longer ago they took place, since the relation of the local duration to the observed duration is, like the wavelength, proportional to the growth of the scale factor.

Comment: Say we observe a blue giant located far far away. Beside seeing it red shifted we will see its lifetime longer than what it was there. This is simply expansion of space between ignition and end of the star. Right?

Comment: Right, the observed duration is longer by the same factor the distance between comoving objects grew in the time the light travelled from A to B. The small gravitational redshift of the star's surface is simply multiplied with the large redshift from the recessional velocity, and if there is a peculiar velocity also with the special relativistic redshift relative to the local frame.